# Ethernet interface number changed, and old one does not exist, but does not leave IP address

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ip-address, static-ip

I have a virtual machine with Mandriva 2007.0 (yes, old - unfortunately we do not have a choice here). Anyway, the problem:

Before reboot: active network interface = eth0. No other interfaces present, and network manager confirms this. Static IP address set to 172.31.2.22. No issues, everything working properly, routing et al.

-------Reboot---------

After reboot: active network interface = eth1, with a DHCP address. Network manager shows eth0 as disconnected, and not connectable. When I try to set eth1 up with the static IP address (same one), it says "In Use". I then tried `ifconfig eth0 172.31.2.29` just to free it up from the eth0 interface so I could use it with eth1 (since this is connected).

Result:

```
ifconfig eth0 172.31.2.29
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
eth0: unknown interface: No such device
```

Nothing else changed. Any ideas what could be happening, or at least how I can get my IP address back?

Comment: Reason for the downvote, please?

Answer (score 1):

What do you get if you try this?

```
ifconfig eth1 172.31.2.22
```

Also, what does

```
route -n
```

show? Do you have a route for that network? Via what interface?

And finally, what happens if you try to ping the address and then look it up on the arp table with arp -an?

Comment: I rebuilt the system so can't try that. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here (been a while since I saw Mandriva) but if this was Redhat I'd check that you do not have a HWADDR= line in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0. If that line exists it will not apply the eth0 configuration to a network adapter with a different MAC address.

Comment: This is actually Mandriva. I'll check though, and see if I find it.

Comment: No, no such line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If Kudzu is installed on your system, try removing it.  If the MAC address of your interface has changed for some reason, Kudzu will interpret this as a new network card and result in the behavior that you've described.

Before you reboot, you may also need to modify a file somewhere under `/etc/udev`.  Try this:

```
grep -rl 'eth[01]' /etc/udev
```

And then remove any matching lines.  Whereby "remove" I mean "remove them from the file but preserve them for posterity in case you remove the wrong things".

Answer (score 0):

Also see: [NIC reordering on RHEL5/CentOS 5](https://serverfault.com/questions/220684/nic-reordering-on-rhel5-centos-5)

Comment: Well, there was only one NIC in that system, so it shouldn't have reordered. Anyway, I rebuilt the system. Thanks though!